# How to connect to local ip address

Tags: java, sockets

I have absolutely no idea what I am doing wrong. About a month ago, I set up my router to work with a server/socket connection in Java. I just moved back to my apartment, and am using a different router with a different ip in a different area.

Connecting to localhost (as the default) with my ServerSocket, and then connecting to the ip I get from whatsmyip.org as the hostname for the client socket, shouldn't I be able to connect?

The server and client are running on the same computer, and if I switch the hostname of the client to localhost, the connection works perfectly. I have a port forwarding set up to my computer's ip address that the router gets for me (not from whatsmyip.org) to port 1640, which is what I was using back at my old place where it was working. What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT 1: I am using DynDNS.com to set up a hostname URL that links to my computer's IP, which I then have all of the clients connect to. The client program can be on any computer anywhere. Before I switch routers, this was working perfectly. I was using the Dynamic DNS feature of the router using my DynDNS account, which was set up on my old router, and my new one. So basically, I should just use my old router?

Comment: as slipperyseal said below . depending upon the make of the router it might not be able to hairpin traffic, meaning go out / in on the same interface.  What are you trying to do connecting to your self in this way? Normally you just use localhost (127.0.0.1/::1).

Answer (score 1):

Some routers will not route the external IP while you are on the internal network. I had a router which was like this. Try connecting from an external location (have a friend try, connect to a remote server and connect back in, or use a device connected to 3G wireless etc).

But im not sure from your question if you actually want to connect from the outside. If you dont, there is no need to creating the port forward (in fact you are just making your server visible to the world unnecessarily). Use the local address of your machine (192.168.x.x / 10.1.1.* etc depending on your router) from any machine within your LAN.